# How to configure bindings in Dashcode from a JSON DataSource to a Popup (design-time)?

Tags: binding, dashcode

**Background**:
I have an Apple Dashcode v3 project in which there is a "Popup Button" UI element.  I have a datasource that references a JSON file. The datasource correctly reads the JSON file at design-time and shows content containing two records, which matches the structure of the JSON file.

Example of fields for each record in the array within the JSON file:
"displayName" : "Woodster",
"uid" : "12345"

**Objective**:
To have the popup's items populate using the content of the datasource.   The datasource provides the content, and displayName and uid fields provide the display and content values, respectively.

**Current Results**: The popup does have two items in it (good!), but they are both listed as "unknown" (!good)

--

I figure I must be binding thePopup.displayValues incorrectly, so I'll indicate how it is setup and hope someone can correct me.

Popup.content [boundTo] dataSource [usingKeyPath] content

Popup.displayValue [boundTo] dataSource [usingKeyPath] displayName || *.displayName || content.displayName  // these are ones I've tried, no luck.

Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is displayValue [boundTo] dataSource.content.displayName

I'm not sure why this didn't work before, but it seems to work great now.